# How to get the duplicate rows based on the 95% criteria in Pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas

For example I have a data frame with 70 columns and want to get the duplicate records(rows) with 95% match. To get 100% match we can use duplicated() but in order to get duplicate match with 95% threshold what need to be done.

**Sample Dataset:**

[image]
In above dataset there are 16 columns out of which if 15(95%) are same then it should return it as Duplicate.

**Output Dataset:** output dataset will have 1st, 3rd and 4th row as duplicate as 1st and 4th are 100% matching and 3rd is 95%(15th columns values) matching. 2nd row will not be there in output as criteria for 95% is not matching.
**Note:** Out of 16 if any 15 columns are matching between 2 rows it should result as duplicate

**Thanks in advance....**

Comment: You could use the `subset` argument of the `duplicated` method to simply pass all combinations of 15 columns and check for exact duplicates in that subset.

Comment: Thanks For your response. Column names are not defined... Its dynamic

Comment: If you have a pandas dataframe it would always have columns. If by dynamic you mean that your column names may change you can simply get the column names using the `columns` attribute and get your subset from that.

Comment: Is it any 95% of the columns, for any number of columns? Or is it out of 16 columns in this dataframe, these specific 15 must match?

Comment: out of 16 any 15 column should match... No specific column